# Why do my three.js examples not load properly?

Tags: html, google-chrome, loading, webgl, three.js

I just downloaded Mr. Doob's three.js project. In the examples folder, anything that doesn't use a model or texture will load up properly. The ones with models or textures show up blank. I don't understand why. I can webgl examples with models and textures to work on the three.js website. Can anybody help, I am stumped...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run chrome using the `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally

Also, here's some discussions on how they're trying to solve this:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=121406 
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47416