# Problems loading three.js 3D models and materials

Tags: macos, three.js

I just downloaded Mr. Doob's three.js project. In the examples folder, anything that doesn't use a model or texture will load up properly. The ones with models or textures show up blank. I don't understand why. I can see webgl examples with models and textures on the three.js website. But when I try to run locally it doesn't work. Can anybody help, I am stumped...

i've tried solving the issue using these posts:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19881735/three-js-example-code-from-stackoverflow-not-working) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888051/why-do-my-three-js-examples-not-load-properly)

I'm running Mac OSX 10.10.1 with NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M and updated Chrome flagged to run locally. I've tried moving the three.min.js file around to see if that would change anything. Are there issues with the newest chrome for mac?  I really want to get started on some three.js loaders for OBJs - please help!

Answer (score 3):

Open up terminal, navigate to your folder where index.html lives, then type in

*(for python 26)*

python -m SimpleHTTPServer

*(for python 3)*

python -m http.server

Now navigate to localhost:8000 in your browser.

The reason for this is because you need to host a web server for the browser to fetch files, such as textures, shaders, etc, using ajax.

Comment: Thanks! This worked! I was trying to run MAMP as a local server but couldn't get it working.